# On relating functions to one another before calculations

Tags: functions

I am preparing three functions:

RR[x_] := [Minus]0.055157 + 0.0585214 x^2 [Minus] 0.000584129 x^3
CC[x_] := 2.9354 [Minus] 0.0688244 x^2 + 0.000581287 x^3

and finally

PP[x_] := RR - CC

But this last command does not give any function at all, only

Function[x, RR - CC]

which is useless for both integration, differentiation and any operation what so ever.

What is wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe use `PP[x_] := RR[x] - CC[x]` or `PP[x] := RR[x] - CC[x]` do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

R[x] and R are 2 different identities. A function always needs an argument.

Your input should read:

```
RR[x_] := -0.055157 + 0.0585214 x^2[Minus] 0.000584129 x^3 
CC[x_] := 2.9354 - 0.0688244 x^2 + 0.000581287 x^3
PP[x_] = RR[x] - CC[x]
```

Comment: Thanks, I did, but I got: Set::write: Tag Integer in 0[x_] is Protected.

Comment: maybe start a fresh kernel